# How to generate a list of combinations of groups of similar data based on variable keys in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I have recipe data that looks like:-

```
  ZONE AREA LOC    DEPT FGOOD INGTYP INGRED
   4    EC  1213    62  5476    I    105
   4    EC  1213    62  5476    I    2834
   4    EC  1213    62  5476    I    16196
   4    EC  1213    62  5476    I    190226
   4    EC  1213    62  5476    I    207075
   4    EC  1213    62  5476    I    333554
   4    EC  1261    62  5476    I    2834
   4    EC  1261    62  5476    I    16196
   4    EC  1261    62  5476    I    190226
   4    EC  1261    62  5476    I    207075
   4    EC  1261    62  5476    I    333554
   4    EC  1265    62  5476    I    2834
   4    EC  1265    62  5476    I    16196
   4    EC  1265    62  5476    I    190226
   4    EC  1265    62  5476    I    207075
   4    EC  1265    62  5476    I    333554
```

For roughly 2,400,000 records.
I need to show unique combinations across ZONE & AREA as

```
  ZONE AREA    FGOOD  INGTYP  INGRED     VERSION     
   4    EC      5476    I     105          1
   4    EC      5476    I     2834         1 
   4    EC      5476    I     16196        1
   4    EC      5476    I     190226       1
   4    EC      5476    I     207075       1
   4    EC      5476    I     333554       1

   4    EC      5476    I     2834         2
   4    EC      5476    I     16196        2
   4    EC      5476    I     190226       2
   4    EC      5476    I     207075       2
   4    EC      5476    I     333554       2
```

Where the distinction is that one finished good combination include the ingredient 105, and the other does not include it, so 2 unique recipes are required among the group of 3 recipes from the source data.

I'm struggling with the combination of CTEs, subqueries or other required to get these results in Oracle.

Thanks!

Comment: Unclear. Please clarify what you mean by "one finished good combination includes the ingredient 105, and the other does not include it, so two unique recipes are required among the group of three recipes from the source data." Your expected result has duplicates.

Comment: The wages of sin is eternal on-the-fly normalisation.

Comment: GurV, yes, I'm trying to get unique "groups" of ingredients of various recipes.  One location may add mushrooms to their pizza, while the other location do not, for example.  So, there will obviously be duplicate ingredients, but not within a unique recipe, or combination of ingredients.

Comment: What constitutes a recipy?

Comment: Rene, the table is obviously not normalized, but a recipe would constitute 1 to many ingredients (INGRED) that result in a single finished good (FGOOD).  Recipe ingredients can vary across locations (LOC), so the challenge is to find the many possible ingredient lists across the companies (ZONE), to reduce the number of recipes in the final, normalized list.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
select ZONE,AREA,FGOOD,INGTYP,VERSION
from yourtable
group by ZONE,AREA,FGOOD,INGTYP,VERSION
-- where .... -- as needed
having sum(case when INGRED = 105 then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

But the majority of your question just isn't clear enough to suggest more

Comment: Any WHERE or HAVING should compare to a column, not a constant, as I have to apply this logic to over 2.4 million non-normalized records.  I can already compare where ingredient counts, but need to compare the actual ingredients by (key) number and description.

Comment: It is **not** a constant. It is a SUM (of a case expression that refereces an ingredient) And as: ` I need to show unique combinations across ZONE & AREA` grouping appears aspropriate.`  hence use of the having clause.

Comment: I was referring to the CASE statement with the reference to the INGRED as a constant ("INGRED = 105").  I would essentially need a self-referencing JOIN with a CTE, WITH temp table or materialized view, so I could compare all 2,400,000 records to one another.

Comment: Theses are your words: `Where the distinction is that one finished good combination include the ingredient 105` Thus, somehow, somewhere,  `105` will be used by the query and the approach shown above meets the stated requirement.  2.4 million rows isnt that scary. As a side note: a case **statement** is a pl/sql branching mechanism and differs from a case  **expression**  used in sql.

Comment: Yes, those are my quite literal words for the example posted.  The problem clearly states there are 2.4 million records, so a dose of both deductive and inductive reasoning would be required.  I'm sorry about the confusion.  I have worked out a solution, and will post details as time permits.

Comment: Right. Inductive reasoning was prompted. I will most likely delete this answer - sorry but  didn't understand at the time.

Answer (score 0):

This approach would locate the first and last sets within the partition of `ZONE,AREA,DEPT,FGOOD,INGTYP,INGRED`

It does use 2 windowing functions `row_number()` and  `count()` however this will minimize the passes through the table. The final order by clause is cosmetic, hence it is optional.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/91a2d/3)

```
CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE
    (ZONE int, AREA varchar(2), LOC int, DEPT int, FGOOD int, INGTYP varchar(1), INGRED int)
;

INSERT INTO YOURTABLE
    (ZONE, AREA, LOC, DEPT, FGOOD, INGTYP, INGRED)
VALUES
    (4, 'EC', 1213, 62, 5476, 'I', 105),
    (4, 'EC', 1213, 62, 5476, 'I', 2834),
    (4, 'EC', 1213, 62, 5476, 'I', 16196),
    (4, 'EC', 1213, 62, 5476, 'I', 190226),
    (4, 'EC', 1213, 62, 5476, 'I', 207075),
    (4, 'EC', 1213, 62, 5476, 'I', 333554),
    (4, 'EC', 1261, 62, 5476, 'I', 2834),
    (4, 'EC', 1261, 62, 5476, 'I', 16196),
    (4, 'EC', 1261, 62, 5476, 'I', 190226),
    (4, 'EC', 1261, 62, 5476, 'I', 207075),
    (4, 'EC', 1261, 62, 5476, 'I', 333554),
    (4, 'EC', 1265, 62, 5476, 'I', 2834),
    (4, 'EC', 1265, 62, 5476, 'I', 16196),
    (4, 'EC', 1265, 62, 5476, 'I', 190226),
    (4, 'EC', 1265, 62, 5476, 'I', 207075),
    (4, 'EC', 1265, 62, 5476, 'I', 333554)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  *
from (
      select
          *
          , row_number() over(partition by ZONE,AREA,DEPT,FGOOD,INGTYP,INGRED) rn
          , count(*) over(partition by ZONE,AREA,DEPT,FGOOD,INGTYP,INGRED) cn
      from yourtable t
    ) d
where rn = 1 or rn=cn
order by 
   ZONE,AREA,DEPT,FGOOD,INGTYP,rn,INGRED
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/91a2d/3/0)**:

```
| zone | area |  loc | dept | fgood | ingtyp | ingred | rn | cn |
|------|------|------|------|-------|--------|--------|----|----|
|    4 |   EC | 1213 |   62 |  5476 |      I |    105 |  1 |  1 |
|    4 |   EC | 1213 |   62 |  5476 |      I |   2834 |  1 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1265 |   62 |  5476 |      I |  16196 |  1 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1261 |   62 |  5476 |      I | 190226 |  1 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1213 |   62 |  5476 |      I | 207075 |  1 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1261 |   62 |  5476 |      I | 333554 |  1 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1261 |   62 |  5476 |      I |   2834 |  3 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1261 |   62 |  5476 |      I |  16196 |  3 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1265 |   62 |  5476 |      I | 190226 |  3 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1261 |   62 |  5476 |      I | 207075 |  3 |  3 |
|    4 |   EC | 1265 |   62 |  5476 |      I | 333554 |  3 |  3 |
```